# Expand the Expression: $\log\left({(x^2+4)^{1/2}}/\left\{(x^2+1)(x^3 - 7)^2\right\}^{1/2}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Expand the expression:

$$\log\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)(x^3-7)^2}}$$

I got 
$$\frac{1}{2}\biggl(\log(x^2+4)-\log(x^2+1)+2\log(x^3-7)\biggr)$$

but the answer key says:
$$\frac{1}{2}\biggl(\log(x^2+4)-\log(x^2+1)-2\log(x^3-7)\biggr)$$

Is the book incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)(x^3-7)^2}}=\log (\sqrt{x^2+4})-\log \left ( \sqrt{(x^2+1)(x^3-7)^2} \right )...(I) \\( \because  \log \left( \frac{a}{b}\right)=\log a - \log b)$

$\log \sqrt{(x^2+1)(x^3-7)^2} =\log \sqrt{x^2+1}+\log \sqrt{(x^3-7)^2} ...(II)$

Substitute for $\log \sqrt{(x^2+1)(x^3-7)^2}$ from $(II)$ into $(I)$

$\log\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)(x^3-7)^2}}=\log (\sqrt{x^2+4})\color{red}- \underbrace{\left ( \log \sqrt{x^2+1}\color{blue}+\log \sqrt{(x^3-7)^2} \right )}$
 when we open this bracket the minus sign outside/in front of it changes the plus sign inside the bracket as minus

$\therefore \log\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)(x^3-7)^2}}=\log (\sqrt{x^2+4})\color{red}- \log \sqrt{x^2+1}\color{red}-\log \sqrt{(x^3-7)^2} $

What remains is application of $\log a^m=m \log a$ on Right hand side and you will get the answer.

Comment: Great explanation. Thus the minus sign is being distributed?

Comment: Yes, $a-(c+d)=a-c-d$ and $a-(c-d)=a-c+d$

Comment: @user137452, you are welcome, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

No, the book is correct.

$$\log\frac{A}{BC^2}=\log A-\log(BC^2)=\log A-(\log B+\log C^2)=\log A-\log B\color{red}{-}2\log C$$
where $A,B,C$ are positive.

Comment: What do you mean when you say A,B,C are positive?

Comment: Also, I slightly would understand if this was a monomial diving into a binomial, but aren't the two factors in the Denominator being multiplied? Thus the law log(ab) = log a + log b?

Comment: @user137452: For the first comment, $\log_aM$ is defined only when $a\gt 0,a\not =1,M\gt 0$, so I just added it in the answer. For the second, maybe $A/(BC^2)=A\times (1/B)\times (1/C^2)$ is helpful. So, $\log (A/(BC^2))=\log A+\log(1/B)+\log(1/C^2)=\log A-\log B-\log C^2$. I hope this helps!

Comment: Not really. You have to keep in mind that I am a precalculus student.

Comment: @user137452: Well, do you understand $\log (AB)=\log A+\log B$ and $\log (A/B)=\log A-\log B$?

Comment: Yes I do understand those laws.

Comment: @user137452: OK. Then, let $D=BC^2$. So, $\log (A/(BC^2))=\log (A/D)=\log A-\log D$, right? Then, since $\log D=\log (BC^2)=\log B+\log C^2$, we can have $$\log (A/(BC^2))=\log A-\log D=\log A-(\log B+\log C^2)=\log A-\log B\color{red}{-}\log C^2.$$